# impap_tools Mailbox.move showing MailboxExpungeError and UID Command Error (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, imap-tools, mailbox

I have part of a script that move emails from one folder to another folder within the same account. However, when I tried to move one email from one to the another, it's showing me the following errors below. There are two ways in which I've tried.

**Option 1 (sending email one by one):**

```
with Mailbox(email_server).login(email_account,email_password,email_folder) as mailbox:
  for msg in mailbox.fetch():
    res = mailbox.move(msg.uid, destination_folder)
```

[image]

**Option 2 (send all emails):**

```
with Mailbox(email_server).login(email_account,email_password,email_folder) as mailbox:
  print(' - {}'.format(mailbox.move(mailbox.fetch(), '"{}"'.format(destination_folder))))
```

Additionally, may I check with you if **mailbox.uids()** still exist? Because I was also trying to move emails by IDs but there was an error message that it does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have omitted the actual errors? Please post the stack trace you are getting with each option.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for this I have realized I did not past any error messages. Have you seen this error before?